# Working on Kivy App for expense tracking... unable to align the gridlayout

Tags: python, web-applications, kivy

I am working on an expense app for myself. in the second screen i want to move "January" and "year-to-date" label above close to "available balance" and move below section above. I have spent few days but unable to find a solution. I was wondering if you someone could help me on this.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

screen_helper = """

<GoButton>:
    Button:
        font_size: 12
        text: "Search"
        background_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y':0.7}
        #on_release: app.run_test()

<MonthYear@MDTextField>:
    font_size: 20
    hint_text: "Enter Month/Year"
    helper_text: "MM/YYYY"
    helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
    size_hint: None, None
    width:120

ScreenManager:
    MainPage:
    IndividualExpense:
    UploadScreen:
<MainPage>:
    name: 'main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: '8dp'
        

        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Home'

        MDLabel:
            text: "  Expenses" 
            font_style: 'Subtitle1'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]   
            
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Cell phone'
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Grocery'
                
                 
        MDToolbar:
                
            left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: app.mainPageScreen()],   ["file-table-outline", lambda x: app.IndivdualExpenseScreen()], ["view-compact", lambda x: app.listOfStocksScreen()],]
       
    
    
<IndividualExpense>:
    name: 'indExp'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: '8dp'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Cell Phone'
        
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            FloatLayout:
                MonthYear
                    pos_hint: {'x':0.025, 'y': .7}
            FloatLayout:

                Button:
                    font_size: 14
                    size_hint: 0.4,0.15
                    text: "Submit"
                    background_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                    pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "top":0.93}

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size: root.width-300, root.height-300

            FloatLayout:

                MDLabel:
                    text: '  Available Balance'
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y':1}
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size: root.width-300, root.height-300
            FloatLayout:

                MDLabel:
                    text: ' January'
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y':1}
            FloatLayout:

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Year-to-Date'
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y':1}
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  Monthly Budget: '
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  MTD Expense: '
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  YTD Budget: '
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  YTD Expense: '
                
        
        
            
                
        
        
        MDToolbar:
                
            left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: app.mainPageScreen()],   ["file-table-outline", lambda x: app.IndivdualExpenseScreen()], ["view-compact", lambda x: app.listOfStocksScreen()],]
       
        
<UploadScreen>:
    name: 'upload'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Upload'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
        
"""



class MainPage(Screen):
    pass


class IndividualExpense(Screen):
    pass


class UploadScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GoButton(FloatLayout):
    pass
# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainPage(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(IndividualExpense(name='indExp'))
sm.add_widget(UploadScreen(name='upload'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def mainPageScreen(self):
        self.root.current = 'main'
        self.root.transition.direction = 'left'
    
    def IndivdualExpenseScreen(self):
        self.root.current = 'indExp'
        self.root.transition.direction = 'right'

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```

[See second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8xBL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of the `<IndividualExpense>:` rule in your `kv`:

```
<IndividualExpense>:
    name: 'indExp'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: '8dp'
        
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Cell Phone'
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            MonthYear:
                
            Widget:
                size_hint_x: 0.3

            Button:
                font_size: 14
                size_hint: 0.3,0.15
                text: "Submit"
                background_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                
            Widget:
                size_hint_x: 0.1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            MDLabel:
                text: '  Available Balance'
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y':1}
                
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size_hint_y: 0.8

            MDLabel:
                text: ' January'
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'top':1}
                size_hint_y: 0.2

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Year-to-Date'
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'top':1}
                size_hint_y: 0.2
                
            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: 0.8
                cols: 1
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  Monthly Budget: '
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  MTD Expense: '
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  YTD Budget: '
                MDLabel:
                    text: '  YTD Expense: '

        MDToolbar:
            left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: app.mainPageScreen()],   ["file-table-outline", lambda x: app.IndivdualExpenseScreen()], ["view-compact", lambda x: app.listOfStocksScreen()],]
```

I have removed several `FloatLayouts` that seemed to serve no purpose. I have also removed some `size` properties (they have no effect unless `size_hints` are `None`). Since your base layout in this rule is a `BoxLayout`, each child of that `BoxLayout` will be given a share of the vertical space based on their `size_hint_y` values. Similar approach for `GridLayouts`.

Comment: @ John Anderson - Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the time you took not only to resolve the issue but go over my code as well. Once again, thank you!